# Display image from array of pixels on Canvas with OpenCV and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, opencv, canvas

I am receiving some images in an array of pixel values (**var image**) from a MQTT subscription and I would like to paint those images on my html website in a canvas while they are being read. I am using Javascript to get the images and OpenCV.js to read the array of pixel values in the image and draw it on the canvas, but I only get a black square. The code is as follows:

```js
function onMessageArrived(message) {
    var data = JSON.parse(message.payloadString);
    var image = data.image; //300x400x3
    var metadata = data.metadata;
    document.getElementById("metadata").innerHTML += '<span>Metadata: ' + metadata + '</span><br/>';

    var width = image.length;
    var height = image[0].length;
    var c = document.getElementById("images_canvas");

    let mat = cv.matFromArray(width, height, cv.CV_8UC3, image);
    cv.cvtColor(mat, mat, cv.COLOR_BGR2BGRA);
    //let dsize = new cv.Size(400, 400);
    //cv.resize(mat, mat, dsize, 0, 0, cv.INTER_AREA);
    cv.imshow("images_canvas", mat);
    mat.delete();
```

As you can see, the array has shape 300x400x3 (three channels) and I am trying to convert it to the 4 channels (RGBA) required by canvas, but I get no luck. Is it because of the shape of the array?

How can I solve this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

How are your reading in your image?  That might be your problem.  It's Base64 in JSON?

```
let src = cv.imread('canvasInput');
let dst = new cv.Mat();
cv.cvtColor(src, dst, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGBA, 0);
cv.imshow('canvasOutput', dst);
src.delete(); dst.delete();
```